# Describe a PDA that accepts the language L = {w | w = a^n b^n c^n , N > 0}

Tags: formal-languages

I was wondering could somebody give me an idea on how to answer this. This computation should start with an empty string >q0---->q1. How does the stack be incorporated into this question? sorry, new to this, any advice would be great.

Describe a PDA that accepts the language L = {w | w = a^n b^n c^n , N > 0}

Comment: There isn’t one: this language is not context-free.

Comment: thanks for the reply, how is this language not context-free?

Comment: Well try the theorems you know about context-free languages and see where you get, then edit the question to include your thoughts.

Comment: @Conor94: See my answer and the material linked from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This language is probably the most classic example of language that is *not* context-free, so it cannot be recognized by a pushdown automaton. The fact that it is not context-free is easily demonstrated using the [pumping lemma for context-free languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages); in fact, that article uses it to demonstrate the use of the lemma.